# Is this an appropriate place for questions about Rovio?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I received a [Rovio](http://www.wowwee.com/en/support/rovio) for xmas, and I'm wondering if this is an appropriate place to ask questions about it?

Answer (score 2):

Questions about electronics and robotics are on-topic here, but not general consumer electronics.

Good:

- What techniques are best for exploring and mapping environments with robots?
- How do I build a better power supply for my Rovio?

Bad:

- How many songs can I fit in my iPod?
- Where can I buy a Rovio?

Ask away, (the worst that can happen is that the community votes it down).

Comment: Well, the Rovio is both a robot, and a consumer electronic device, which is why I asked here first.

Comment: Good point about the worst that can happen is it gets voted down and closed. Can't we fix this? How do we get the electronic equivalent of tar and feathering, stocks and pillary on the courthouse steps with a box of rotten fruit nearby, public flogging, and a good old fashioned lynch mob.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about Rovio as a general consumer, then no.

If you are asking about Rovio while wearing the hat of a robotics enthusiast, expert, or hacker... then possibly.

It depends entirely on the point of view and purpose of the *author*. Consider [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. So, even though they are often asking about the *same exact computers* you and I use, they are **not asking** *"how do I configure my friend's computer"* questions. That would be off topic.

In that same vein, asking about how to use, or purchase, or take advantage of the capabilities of Rovio would be off topic. But, if you were asking about *expert-level* considerations: algorithms, hacking, the internal electronics, the physics, etc… it might be considered on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to ask about the Rovio from a robotics aspect (mechanical, electro-mechanical, control systems, etc.) I would encourage you to head over to robotics.stackexchange.com, where most any technical question about that little fellow will be welcome.